# How best to handle Azure DevOps 'region move requests are currently delayed due to ongoing deployments'

Tags: azure-devops

I have requested an Azure DevOps organisation region move before Christmas. It has been repeatedly delayed with the message

> Please note that region move requests are currently delayed due to ongoing deployments. We may not be able to perform the change at your requested time and may ask you to reschedule. We apologize for the potential delay and appreciate your patience!

This is the only message I have, I have received no other email detailing what I should do

Anyone know am I best to

1. Just wait i.e do not reschedule anything, even though the target date is now in the past
2. Reschedule the move to a date in the future using the virtual assistant wizard
3. Cancel the old request and start the process again from scratch
4. Something else

Comment: Stackoverflow is mainly issue-handling's open forum while your current question is organization region migration targeting to Azure DevOps, which need assistance of the product group. Thus the best contact channel is here: https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21, the product support engineers will then contact the product group and offer efficient assistance. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

As noted above in the comment from Edward, you need to talk to the product group via https://developercommunity2.visualstudio.com/report?entry=problem&space=21

I did this an was told the best solution was to cancel the migration request (for a date that had passed) and create a new request. I did this and my migration was done as planned on the expected date.